# Extract the very first last modified date from Azure Data Lake topic using Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Is there any method available in Azure Data Factory to get the very first last modified date from Azure Data Lake. Filename can be anything. I need the last modified date of a very first file uploaded in the data lake topic.

For Eg:

```
+----------+------------------+
| Filename | LastModifiedDate |
+----------+------------------+
| File1    | 2021-10-01       |
| File2    | 2021-10-02       |
| File1    | 2021-10-03       |
+----------+------------------+
```

Expected output: 2021-10-01

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Azure Data Lake can contain multiple containers. Do you want to retrieve the last modified date from a specific container, or just all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go through each folder in the datalake with `Get-Metadata Activity` like is done in this archived question on [MSFT Forum](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZJS2nhEmcfgJ:https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/questions/136815/lates-file-extraction-azure-data-factory.html).

Depending on the number of folders and files, it is a rather brute force way of retrieving the earliest date of any file in your datalake.

I found it easier to use PowerShell;

```
$storageAccount = 'storageAccountName';
$resourceGroupName = 'resourceGroupName';
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccount | Select-Object -Property Value -First 1).Value
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$allblobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containername -Context $context 
$allblobs | Sort-Object -Property LastModified | Select-Object -Property Name,LastModified -First 1
```

This PowerShell script returns the Name and LastModified datetime of the file with the earliest LastModified value. However, running a PowerShell script directly using ADF is not so straight forward. Here is [an article by Bob Blackburn](https://medium.com/hitachisolutions-braintrust/3-steps-to-run-powershell-in-azure-data-factory-e7c73d38e548) on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you. I hope this will resolve my problem.